# When using different version of jQuery it gives Uncaught Typeerror

Tags: jquery

I am using following JQuery in master page, Below is project in asp.net.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>
<%--<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>--%>
<script src="js/jquery-galleryview-1.1/jquery.galleryview-1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-galleryview-1.1/jquery.timers-1.1.2.js"></script>


<%-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

<!-- Preloader js file -->
<script src="js/queryloader2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- For smooth animatin  -->
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>  
<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- slick slider -->
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<!-- superslides slider -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.superslides.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>   
<!-- for circle counter -->
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/master/js/jquery.circliful.min.js'></script>
<!-- Gallery slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.tosrus.min.all.js"></script>   


<!-- Custom js-->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<!--=============================================== 
Template Design By WpFreeware Team.
Author URI : http://www.wpfreeware.com/
====================================================-->
<script src="js1/ajaxupload.js"></script>
<script src="js1/chrome.js"></script>
<script src="js1/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
<script src="js1/html5.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>  
<script src="js1/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
<script src="js1/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
 <script src="js1/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.ui.touch.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="js1/kamal.js"></script>
<script src="js1/paras.js"></script>
<script src="js1/QapTcha.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js1/tabcontent.js"></script>
```

Ιn content page Ι have the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').galleryView({
        panel_width: 600,
        panel_height: 350,
        frame_width: 100,
        frame_height: 100,
        nav_theme: 'custom'
    });
});
</script>
```

But it gives:

> Uncaught Typeerror: galleryView is not a function

Comment: You should assign each version of jQuery to it's own variable, eg `$132`, `$141`. However, you really should just use a single version of jQuery. There may be some work involved in doing it, but it will save you *a lot* of time in maintenance.

Comment: You are including jQuery three times, and `1.4.1` twice, really??? EDIT: oh no, i miss the 1.7.1... So in fact you are including jQuery 4 times, this doesn't really make sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question indent the body properly. 4 spaces indentation is for code sample rendering - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: have you copied the code snippets - *for example, ticker* - from different online tutorials and using different version of `jquery` as a result of that (*as mentioned in those tutorials*)?? If so, please try and test out with latest version of jq or google out to have a compatibilty among them! :)